# django - how to apply custom template filter to absolute url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

I am trying to write a small urlshortener app.

everything is set up well so far. now I am trying to apply the filter to the full url:

`{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ request.get_absolute_url}}` gives me the full url. But if apply my filter like this:

```
href="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ request.get_absolute_url|shortenme}}"
```

my filter isnot getting anything because `request.get_absolute_url` is alone giving empty string.

only `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ request.get_absolute_url}}` is giving the full url I want. How can I apply my filter to the full url?

Comment: Are you sure that `get_absolute_url` is returning the expected value, and not an empty string?

Comment: @Alasdair yep, you are right. it is an empty string. dang it. I thought, ``build_absolute_uri`` with ``get_absolute_url`` together gives me the full path. I will change my question to ask how to apply my filter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests do not have a `get_absolute_url` method.

You want to use `request.path` or `request.get_full_path`. The second includes any query string.

See the docs on [request attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes) for more info.

Comment: thanks, my bad. ``request.build_absolute_uri`` alone is giving the full url. thanks anyway.